# Describing a person who is smirking or whose lips are pursed

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

What is a way to describe a person who is smirking or whose lips are pursed? I'm looking for a simple phrase or word that describes a series of conflicting and contradicting emotions being displayed by a person. The description of the behavior is in an effort to reveal vulnerability. This is to describe the behavior of primary characters in a screenplay.

Comment: A screenplay provides direction to the actor. Before it goes to production, however, it gets reviewed by multiple people. The story is important, but so is the clarity of script, because a director does not want needless work, even if it’s done by a rewrite team. Something simple, like “lips pursed. conflicting triumph and concern” will be the most useful. I’m not a professional screenwriter, but screenplays are readily available. Emulate the successful ones.

Comment: Please say whether you want a noun or an adjective.  Either of these can be said to "describe" a person. Also, do you want to describe someone who is smirking, or do you want to describe a series of emotions. It would be helpful if you gave a sentence or paragraph showing how you want to use the word/phrase - leaving a blank space where it would appear. Thanks.

Comment: As it's a screenplay, it might be better to simply describe rather than wax poetic. Screenplay direction generally does want to tell, not show. Something like "ALICE smirks, but her confidence wavers momentarily."

Comment: Do you mean to reveal the vulnerability of others, or to reveal one's own vulnerability? Smirking is usually the former; pursing the lips is usually the latter (I think).

Answer (score 0):

I first thought of emotions [**convulsing**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/convulse) or [**writhing**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/writhe) across the character's face, but they lack the idea of vulnerability or weakness.

Then the word **flitter** came to mind. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/flitter) has

> **flitter**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> Move quickly in an apparently random or purposeless manner.
> *Her mother paused and several expressions Helene couldn't identify flittered quickly across her face.*

I chose this word because it sounds weak and purposeless, hence *vulnerable*.